# How do I graph a region of some curves

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, regions

how do I graph a region of some curves like y =2x , y =2x -2 , y=x , y=x+1

Plotregion y=2x && y = 2x -2 && y=x %% y=x+1

Answer (score 5):

```
rgn = ImplicitRegion[
   y < x + 1 && y > 2 x - 2 && y > x && y < 2 x, {x, y}];

Show[
 Plot[{2 x, 2 x - 2, x, x + 1}, {x, -1, 4},
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"x", "y"}),
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"],
 RegionPlot[rgn, BoundaryStyle -> None]]
```

[image]